# Py.test searching

Tags: python, pytest

This command does never end, since it searches in a very deep and big data directory:

> py.test --full-trace -k my_test_name

```
stat("/home/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/specialworkflow/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/specialworkflow/239/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/specialworkflow/239/57x/conftest.py", 0x7ffff5e6f1a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/specialworkflow/239/75x", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/specialworkflow/239/75x", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

There is no `__init__.py` file in `/home/foo3_bar_p/archiv/`. Why does py-test scan this big directory?

Answer (score 0):

Because pytest doesn't require `__init__.py` files in tests.

If you don't want it to scan the directory, either pass a path to pytest, or add it to [`norecursedirs`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#confval-norecursedirs).